# What should I do about com.apple.quarantine?

Tags: macos, permissions, java

I've downloaded some `.jar` files from the internet and want to use them under Mac OS X. But the OS seems to have tagged them with the extended attribute com.apple.quarantine (no indication of this until I noticed the "`@`" in the `ls -l` and figured out how to use `ls -l@`) -- apparently because they have been downloaded from the internet. What's the right way to deal with this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This attribute is added so that it can ask for user confirmation the first time the downloaded program is run, to help stop malware.  Upon confirmation the attribute should be removed automatically, and then the program will run normally.

Comment: ahhhhhh.... ok that makes sense. So it's a contract between browser implementations that save files, and the OS and/or Java when it runs executables.

Comment: except it isn't removed on open and seems to persist indefinitely, even when dragged to /Applications

Comment: this comment isn't fully correct anymore; as pointed out, the flag is now kept and Apple is even lying in that they are reporting that the application has been "damaged".

Answer (score 114):

You don't *have* to deal with it. Open it and OS X will ask for your permission. Or like richard suggested, delete it using something like:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine my_jar.jar
```

To do this automatically for any downloaded file you can attach a folder action to the download folder, like described on macosxhints.com in [10.5: Remove the 'downloaded file' warning flag](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071029151619619).

And the following was posted on macosxhints.com a long time ago, for Safari: [10.5: Disable the 'downloaded from internet' file warning](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2009081808315511), claiming one can remove `VerifiedDownloadPlugin.plugin` from `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins`. I did not test that.

As an aside: sometimes one needs to start a single program multiple times on a Mac. That can be done using `cd /Applications/some-application/` followed by `open -n "Application Name.app"`. This really needs the `.app` suffix; running `open -n "Application Name"` might get one GateKeeper stopping access:

> "Application Name" can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.
>
> Your security preferences allow installation of only apps from the Mac App Store and identified developers.

Above, even removing the extended attribute `com.apple.quarantine` does not fix that, but using the `.app` suffix works just fine.

(I am not advising anyone to actually get rid of the security measures.)

Comment: I have a number of files like this and have had to manually remove the xattr as OS X did not ask for permission...

Comment: @Brian, and did right-click, Open not prompt either? (That sometimes helps if OS X does prompt one, but does not show the option to continue.)

Comment: Thanks for the xattr incantation, less bother than figuring out how to trigger some inappropriate (IMO) dialogue on a framework.

Answer (score 31):

```
 xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/file
```

Comment: How do you do this recursively to all files in a directory?

Comment: @landon9720 - The (currently) [below answer](http://superuser.com/questions/28384/#126227) has a [comment](http://superuser.com/questions/28384/what-should-i-do-about-com-apple-quarantine#comment565539_126227) that allows you to instruct xattr to work recursively over contents of a supplied directory

Comment: `find /path/to/dir -exec xattr -d com.apple.quarantine {} \;`

Comment: I use xattr -cr .

Comment: I just found out that Preview sets the quarantine flag upon opening an image file!  I was wondering why it kept on being turned on on files that I'd downloaded  years ago.

Answer (score 7):

You can disable the warnings permanently with `defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool false`. It also disables the Gatekeeper dialogs even if you haven't allowed applications downloaded from anywhere in System Preferences.

Answer (score 5):

I found the following command

```
find Application.app | while read l; do echo $l; xattr -d com.apple.quarantine "$l"; done
```

very helpful when trying to get rid of the attribute. Note the double quotes around `$l` – you need them if your apps folder contains files with a blank in their name.

Comment: You could also use `xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine Application.app`.

Comment: You don't need the while... loop. find can do it all: " find Application.app -print -exec xattr -d com.apple.quarantine {} \;  "

Comment: "option -r not recognized"

Comment: No need to spawn a new process for each file, nor do you have to remove the xattribute from the file if it doesn't have it in the first place: `find . -xattrname com.apple.quarantine -print0 | xargs -0 xattr -d com.apple.quarantine`

Comment: All these command line examples only work when you are in the directory containing the app. @dland `find` also has a `-exec` primary.

`find /Applications -xattrname com.apple.quarantine -exec xattr -d com.apple.quarantine {} \;`

You can replace `/Applications` with the full path you want, e.g. `/Users/jdoe/Downloads`

If you are in the directory where the file is, just do `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine <target>` where `<target>` is a file or app name.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a corollary answer to the question asked. For .app files, the quarantine is placed when the file is run, and removed when the user grants permissions in System Preferences. However, you still can't run the .app until you move it to the Applications folder. This is useful information for when you are distributing .apps informally, but you don't want users to have to run `xattr` as in the accepted answer.

Here's a passive aggressive comment about this insanity.

Comment: I _often_ run apps that are not in /Applications.  Also, the quarantine attribute is on the file as soon as it is downloaded; macOS does not wait until it is run.