# What does the @ mean on the output of "ls" on OS X' terminal?

Tags: macos, permissions, ls

When doing an `ls` in a directory I get the following output:

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 12 xonic  staff    408 22 Jun 19:00 .
drwxr-xr-x   9 xonic  staff    306 22 Jun 19:42 ..
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 xonic  staff   6148 25 Mai 23:04 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--@  1 xonic  staff  17284 22 Jun 00:20 filmStrip.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 xonic  staff   3843 21 Jun 21:20 filmStrip.h
```

I was wondering what the `@` means.

Comment: see also here http://forthescience.org/blog/2007/12/11/macosx-leopard-extended-ls/

Comment: `xattr -r -d com.apple.TextEncoding *` will probably remove it *if* its a text file, like a C++ header or source file, created locally. If you downloaded it, then `xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine *` will likely remove it, so you can do things like edit a Makefile. For some reason, Apple *does not* allow you to edit a Makefile, but *does* allow you to run a Makefile, with `com.apple.quarantine`. Go figure...

Comment: See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42177/what-does-signify-in-unix-file-permissions

Answer (score 92):

It indicates that the file has extended attributes. Use `ls -l@` to see them.

You can use `xattr` to edit these attributes. `xattr -h` will give you the inline help for it.

Comment: thanks. found com.apple.quarantine, here is what that is and how to deal with it for the sake of completeness: http://superuser.com/questions/28384/what-should-i-do-about-com-apple-quarantine

Answer (score 28):

Off the top of my head, I think is has something to do with the file having extended attributes available.  Here's a link to a similar discussion:

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=5791060

So if you see a file with an "@" when you do an ls, try doing this:

```
xattr -l <filename>
```

That should show you the extended attributes.

You can check xattr's help for more details:

```
xattr --help
usage: xattr [-l] file [file ...]
       xattr -p [-l] attr_name file [file ...]
       xattr -w attr_name attr_value file [file ...]
       xattr -d attr_name file [file ...]

The first form lists the names of all xattrs on the given file(s).
The second form (-p) prints the value of the xattr attr_name.
The third form (-w) sets the value of the xattr attr_name to attr_value.
The fourth form (-d) deletes the xattr attr_name.

options:
  -h: print this help
  -l: print long format (attr_name: attr_value)
```

It seems like if you look at the extra attributes with "-l" and then remove them with "-d" it'll probably do what you want.  Practice this in a temporary directory somewhere first though and make sure it works  ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It would seem that the directory in question was marked as com.apple.quarantine, which is a security measure to protect against dodgy scripts and apps from the net. That can't possibly cause the problem of the directory not listing. :/ I'll look around more and post the solution if I find it.

Answer (score 24):

From the `ls(1)` man page on Mac OS X v10.6.1:

> If the file or directory has extended attributes, the permissions
> field printed by the -l option is followed by a '@' character.
> Otherwise, if the file or directory has extended security information
> (such as an access control list), the permissions field printed by the
> -l option is followed by a '+' character.

From the available *options* list:

```
-@      Display extended attribute keys and sizes in long (-l) output.

-e      Print the Access Control List (ACL) associated with the file, if present, in long (-l) output.
```

These will let you see the value of those *extended attributes*. FWIW, [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access-control_list) info can be set using the same `chmod(1)` utility you are probably already aware of.

There doesn't appear to be an easy way from the command line to do anything with extended attributes.

Comment: Extended attributes can be viewed and manipulated with the xattr command (only available in OS X v10.5 and .6).  It doesn't seem to have a man page, but `xattr -h` will print its internal help.

Comment: `xattr` now has a man page, and you can use `xattr -l file` to list all attributes or `xattr -p attribute_name file` to print a specific attribute.

Answer (score 10):

From the [man page for ls](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html):

> If the -l option is given, the following information is displayed for each file: file mode, number of links, owner name, group name, number of bytes in the file, abbreviated month, day-of-month file was last modified, hour file last modified, minute file last modified, and the pathname.
>
> In addition, for each directory whose contents are displayed, the total number of 512-byte blocks used by the files in the directory is displayed on a line by itself, immediately before the information for the files in the directory.
>
> If the file or directory has extended attributes, the permissions field printed by the -l option is followed by a '@' character.  Otherwise, if the file or directory has extended security information (such as an access control list), the permissions field printed by the -l option is fol-lowed followed lowed by a '+' character.

Use:

```
ls -la@e
```

for more information on files or directories with those attributes/information.

Answer (score 9):

This is related to extended attributes and access control.

From the [man page of sun ls](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9kg/index.html):

> The character after permissions is an
>   ACL or extended attributes indicator.
>   This character is an @ if extended
>   attributes are associated with the
>   file and the -@ option is in effect.
>   Otherwise, this character is a plus
>   sign (+) character if a non-trivial
>   ACL is associated with the file or a
>   space character if not.

Answer (score 6):

From the [man page of `ls`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/ls.1.html):

> **The Long Format**
>   […] If the file or directory has extended attributes, the permissions field printed by the `-l` option is followed by a '`@`' character. […]

Comment: Note that the '@' can also hide the '+' that would normally be there to indicate that the file/directory has an ACL associated with it.  Try 'ls -le@O' -- that'll list xattrs, ACL (if present), and also any flags.

Answer (score 6):

The "@" means that the file has "extended attributes" associated with it.

If you do "`ls -@ -l`", you can see what attributes there are for each file. You can also do something like "`xattr -l pgsql.so`" to dump the attributes for a particular file.

Typically they're stuff like old-school FinderInfo, text encoding info, or the "quarantine" info that gives you the "This file was downloaded from the web, are you sure you want to open it?" warning.

Comment: Extended attributes are not unique to the mac platform. A number of operating systems support this file-level feature.

Comment: @iftrue: ultimately it's a file system feature, though.

Answer (score 0):

`-la` or `-al` in command `ls -la` has the following things to add in `ls`

`l` adds following options to `-la`
[image]

`a` option instead adds the hidden files.

Answer to one of the merged questions : [ls -la symbolics... what does that last symbol mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/66722/ls-la-symbolics-what-does-that-last-symbol-mean)