# What is the @ sign signifying when viewing ls -la on a directory?

Tags: linux, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does the @ mean on the output of ls on os x terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/155458/what-does-the-mean-on-the-output-of-ls-on-os-x-terminal)

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jeremysmith  staff  249444 Oct  9 12:03 small.xml
```

and the file as it is uploaded, which will not be parsed:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 jeremysmith  staff  249444 Oct  9 13:17 public/uploads/small.xml
```

I don't understand what the @ is saying about the difference between permissions here.  This is on OSX 10.7.