# How can Mac OS X save details about the URL from which a file has been downloaded?

Tags: macos, permissions

WRT this topic [What should I do about com.apple.quarantine?](https://superuser.com/questions/28384/what-should-i-do-about-com-apple-quarantine) , I want to know how can OS X learn and save those information in the @ field. I'm not looking for a way to disable this feature, but for a code (or pseudocode, idea, whatever) regarding the implementation of this thing. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Daniel mentioned, the browser can store the source URL (and also the referrer) of a downloaded file in the extended attribute `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms`.

First Apple added this to Safari for Mac OS X 10.4, then it was added to Chrome/Chromium [[Issue 22289]](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=22289), and there is an outstanding enhancement request to add it to Firefox [[Bug 337051]](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=337051).

As for the actual code to implement this, check out the [Chromium patch](http://codereview.chromium.org/220037).

Comment: Nice history :-) However, when using Safari I don't see the referrer (or at least not in the new downloads I tried to see if I missed something). Maybe things are different when right-clicking and downloading, or when a downloads starts automatically? (For example, some browsers don't send the referrer when opening links in new windows either.)

Comment: Ah, you're right, `mdls` does show it for downloads that start automatically. And Finder's Get Info shows that as a comma-separated list, which I failed to notice!

Answer (score 7):

After downloading any file, running `xattr file` will show you what the browser has stored in the extended attributes:

```
xattr mydownload.gz
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms
com.apple.quarantine
```

Next, more details:

```
xattr -p com.apple.quarantine mydownload.gz 
0000;4cee9d4b;Safari;24064D6B-9854-46BC-AF73-5DE5F8042D0B|com.apple.Safari

xattr -p com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms mydownload.gz 
62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 A1 01 5F 10 24 68 74 74
70 3A 2F 2F 73 75 [and so on]
```

...or, in readable format:

```
mdls -name kMDItemWhereFroms mydownload.gz
kMDItemWhereFroms = (
    "http://some-url"
)
```

You can set those (or *any* attribute you want) yourself too:

```
xattr -w some-name some-value mydownload.gz
```

The [following](http://hmmaha.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/add-where-from-to-firefox-downloads-mac-os-x/) works too, even though is has different results when running the above commands again:

```
xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms http://example.com mydownload.gz
```

And for the `com.apple.quarantine` attribute, according to [understand](http://code.google.com/p/understand/wiki/MacOSMetadata#Quarantined_Files):

> Typically, the Quarantine data consists of a set of 4 semicolon-delimited values (a set of decimal digits of an unknown purpose - typically 0000, an 8 character [opaque ID](http://code.google.com/p/understand/wiki/MacOSMetadata#Opaque_Quarantine_IDs), the name of the application that created the Quarantined file, and the application's UTI (Uniform Type Identifier) prefixed with a pipe symbol)
>
> For example, for two different files downloaded using Mozilla FireFox, this looks like:
>
> ```
> com.apple.quarantine: 0000;4b392bb2;Firefox;|org.mozilla.firefox
> com.apple.quarantine: 0000;4b38d820;Firefox;|org.mozilla.firefox
> ```

Using Automator's Folder Actions you could run such commands for new files in a specific folder, if that's what you after.

Answer (score 4):

That information is stored in what are called "extended attributes". John Siracusa has an excellent article discussing extended attributes when they were first introduced, in OS X 10.4: http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2005/04/macosx-10-4.ars/7.

It appears there is no longer a man page for the 'xattr' command line tool, but 'xattr -h' should show basic help.

A POSIX/BSD-level API is available in /usr/include/sys/xattr.h which defines C functions such as getxattr(), setxattr(), removexattr(), listxattr(), and their FILE-based cousins. (These commands, unlike 'xattr(1)', do have man pages).

Answer (score 3):

It's set by the application downloading the file. No magic download detection, just an attribute set on the downloaded file by the downloading application.

I just downloaded a zip file using `wget`, Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari, and, as expected, the `wget` download has no extended attributes, the browser downloads have, as they're aware of that feature. Interestingly, the Firefox download set quarantine, but forgot to set `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms`, the information where the downloaded file was originally located (its URL). Safari and Chrome set both, `wget` neither.