# Getting error code -41 when copying files to external drive

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, permissions

I'm having trouble copying some files from my mac to an external hard drive: I keep getting the nondescript "error code -41".

I noticed some of the files with an additional "@" permission bit had the "com.apple.quarantine" flag set. I used the "xattr" command from this article

[What should I do about com.apple.quarantine?](https://superuser.com/questions/28384/what-should-i-do-about-com-apple-quarantine)

to take care of the quarantine flag and sort that out (these files were copied over from another mac on my network, so I guess OS X flagged them as quarantine).

That took care of the problem for those files but I still have some that I can't manually copy over to the external drive. The only other thing I've noticed is that some of these files have a an extra permission bit: "drwxr-xr-x+" which I haven't been successful in googling. Aside from that I don't see anything else. Also, Disk Utility says everything's fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` means there are POSIX ACLs; <strike>try the `xattr` command.</strike> `xattr` doesn't appear to show ACLs.  `ls -le` does.  Also check `chflags` output.  (OSX puts too many different things in too many different places; you can get `ls` to show ACLs and EAs but not `chflags`.)

Comment: Use `ls -lO` to show file flags.  `ls -le@O` will show ACLs, xattrs, and flags.

Comment: *sigh* I swear I went back and forth over the manpage multiple times after discovering `-e` (I already knew about `-@`) looking for that option.

Comment: Running 'ls -lO' didn't show any 'uchg' flags set for the files in question or anything like that, e.g., 'drwxr-xr-x+ 24 tatami  staff  -  816 Dec 28  2009 BroadphaseCollision' is what shows up for one such directory. Doesn't look like any other flags are set, but still getting 'error -41'.