# Apps not starting on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I have a strange problem, some apps that I download do not launch. There are 2 scenarios

1. The application starts but keeps bouncing, once I click the bouncing icon in the tray it disappears. The process also closes in activity monitor
2. The application fails to start, how ever many times I launch it, it refuses. The process does not even show up in activity monitor

What I have done so far to resolve:

- Repaired permissions
- Clear all cache/temp using CleanMyMac
- Used DiskWarrior via OS and not during boot

Additional Info:

```
 Model Name:    MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro5,2
  Processor Name:   Intel Core 2 Duo
  Processor Speed:  2.8 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache: 6 MB
  Memory:   8 GB
  Bus Speed:    1.07 GHz
  Boot ROM Version: MBP52.008E.B05
  SMC Version (system): 1.42f4
```

Comment: Something interesting in the system log in `Console.app`?

Comment: [Try to remove](http://superuser.com/questions/28384/what-should-i-do-about-com-apple-quarantine) the `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute from the applications in Terminal. Maybe there's a problem with the dialog usually asking for permission to run downloaded software.

Comment: I got this in the log:
`([0x0-0x9f19f1].com.fiplab.facetabpro[12505]): posix_spawn("/Applications/MenuTab Pro for Facebook.app/Contents/MacOS/MenuTab Pro for Facebook", ...): Permission denied
May 24 00:05:03 kps-MacBook-Pro com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[141] ([0x0-0x9f19f1].com.fiplab.facetabpro[12505]): Exited with code: 1
 `

Comment: these are the permissions:
`drwxr-xr-x   3 kps  staff   102 Dec 31 15:00 MenuTab Pro for Facebook.app`

Comment: Please post `ls -le@` output.

Comment: Daniel, I will post the output once I get home. I did do a ls -l@ and it did not show the quarantine flag on the .app file

Comment: Run `ls -l` on the actual executable file in the app bundle mentioned in the error message. Is the executable flag missing?

Comment: What I understood from your last comment was I go to "Show package contents" and then run a ls -l there? Is that correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3547/discussion-between-kps-and-daniel-beck)

Comment: Given that I mentioned both the missing execute permission and the quarantine flag, I posted an answer to this. To mark this question answered, please click the checkmark next to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual executable, `/Applications/MenuTab Pro for Facebook.app/Contents/MacOS/MenuTab Pro for Facebook` doesn't have the execute permission. Resolve by running:

> `sudo chmod +x '/Applications/MenuTab Pro for Facebook.app/Contents/MacOS/MenuTab Pro for Facebook'`

---

Additionally, parts of the application have the `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute set, as determined by `ls -l@`. Remove [as described in this other topic](https://superuser.com/questions/28384/what-should-i-do-about-com-apple-quarantine). This shouldn't be an issue, but you never know. It sometimes prevents applications from being started from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when that happens could be one of this two reasons:

- The application doesn't support Intel Mac (only power pc)
- The application doesn't support Lion

Have you checked if the applications you are trying to run are for Intel Mac and Lion?

Comment: A Google search reveals the app is in the Mac App Store...

Comment: So the app is supported on Lion and this is not the only app that I am having issues with, it just so happens it was available for me to post info about.

Comment: When I cd into the .app this is the attributes:
`Lalys-MacBook-Pro:contents laly$ ls -le@ 
total 16 
drwxr-xr-x 5 laly staff 170 Dec 31 15:00 Frameworks 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 laly staff 1840 Dec 31 15:00 Info.plist 
com.apple.quarantine  15 
drwxr-xr-x 3 laly staff 102 Dec 31 15:00 Library 
drwxr-xr-x 3 laly staff 102 Dec 31 15:00 MacOS 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 laly staff 8 Dec 31 15:00 PkgInfo 
com.apple.quarantine  15 
drwxr-xr-x 67 laly staff 2278 Dec 31 15:00 Resources 
drwxr-xr-x 3 laly staff 102 Dec 31 15:00 _CodeSignature`

Answer (score 0):

For the records: the application [The Unarchiver](http://itunes.apple.com/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12&ls=1) may cause this issue.

> Version 3.2:
>   * Added a workaround for a sandbox bug in Mac OS X that was causing extracted apps to not launch properly.

Check this thread in [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3907713?start=0&tstart=0).