# Why do my .tex files have different permissions?

Tags: macos, permissions, latex

I have a folder of `.tex` files in my Dropbox folder. For some reason not all files have the same permissions.
Running `ls -@l` shows that a certain set has permissions set to `-rwxr-xr-x@` owned by `com.apple.FinderInfo` or `com.apple.quarantine`.

The other set has the permissions set to `-rw-r--r--`.

Why is there a difference between these similar files?

Comment: This may be relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/28384/what-should-i-do-about-com-apple-quarantine

Comment: @ReubenL. I saw that question, but I have not downloaded the files from the web. All files are created on this machine. However, they do reside in a Dropbox folder, so that might play a role.