# Files downloaded on Mac generate corresponding 4-KiB hidden files on Windows PC

Tags: windows, mac, download

For some reason, whenever I download a file on a Mac and then navigate to the file on a Windows PC, the file is always accompanied by a hidden file with exactly the same name as the downloaded file (right down to the file extension) except for an additional “._” tacked onto the beginning.

So, for instance, I download

- **Teddy.png**

on a Mac, and, when I go to the file’s location in Windows Exploder, I see

- **Teddy.png**
- **._Teddy.png** [hidden file]

These extra hidden files are *always* exactly 4 KiB (4096 B) in size, no matter what the size of the original downloaded file.

This happens on Windows 8.1...

[image: W8.1 phantom files]

...on Windows 7...

[image: W7 phantom files]

...on Windows XP...

[image: WXP phantom files]

...and on Windows 2000.

[image: W2000 phantom files]

(It probably happens on other Windows versions as well, but these are the ones I’ve specifically encountered it with.)

This *never* happens with files downloaded on a Windows PC, no matter what version of Windows said PC is running.

Deleting these phantom 4-KiB hidden files is a pain in the ass, especially if I’ve been downloading a lot of files recently (and thus ending up with a lot of these phantom files).

Why is Windows generating these extra useless files whenever it encounters a file downloaded on a Mac, and how do I stop it from doing so?

(The drive the files are being saved to is a 64-GB exFAT-formatted USB3 flashdrive, if that helps.)

Comment: I wonder if it IS tge PC. Id speculate its.the mac writing metadata of some sort which it would normally put in the filesystem but cant?

Comment: all filenames starting with . (dot) will be hidden in macos

Comment: Could you crop the screenshots in your question?  It'll make the images bigger and remove distractions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FAT32 and ExFAT cannot store all the information about a file that HFS+, JHFS+ and AFPS can, such as [extended attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes) or the legacy [resource fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork#Compatibility_problems). (For example, macOS uses an xattr to mark downloaded files as ["quarantined"](https://superuser.com/questions/28384/what-should-i-do-about-com-apple-quarantine).)

On those file systems, macOS (OS X) *itself* will create a separate file to hold this information, known as the "AppleDouble" file. You can remove these files by using the Terminal application command called `dot_clean`. Below is the man page.

```
DOT_CLEAN(1)              BSD General Commands Manual             DOT_CLEAN(1)

NAME
     dot_clean -- Merge ._* files with corresponding native files.

SYNOPSIS
     dot_clean [-fmnsv] [--keep=[mostrecent|dotbar|native]] [dir ...]

DESCRIPTION
     For each dir, dot_clean recursively merges all ._* files with their cor-
     responding native files according to the rules specified with the given
     arguments.  By default, if there is an attribute on the native file that
     is also present in the ._ file, the most recent attribute will be used.

     If no operands are given, a usage message is output.  If more than one
     directory is given, directories are merged in the order in which they are
     specified.

OPTIONS
     -f      Flat merge.  Do not recursively merge all directories in the
             given dir.  This is off by default.

     -h      Help. Prints verbose usage message.

     -m      Always delete dot underbar files.

     -n      Delete dot underbar file if there is no matching native file.

     -s      Follow symbolic links.  This will follow symbolic dot underbar
             files when they are found.

     -v      Print verbose output.

     --keep=mostrecent
             The default option.  If an attribute is associated with a data
             fork, use that.  Otherwise, use information stored in the Apple-
             Double file.  Note that the native fork’s data is preferred even
             if the data in the AppleDouble file is newer.

     --keep=dotbar
             Always use information stored in the AppleDouble file, replacing
             any extended attributes associated with the native file.

     --keep=native
             Always use the information associated with the data fork, ignor-
             ing any AppleDouble files.

EXAMPLES
     The following is how to do an dot_clean merge on the mounted volume test,
     always using the dot underbar information.

           dot_clean --keep=dotbar /Volumes/test

DIAGNOSTICS
     The dot_clean utility exits 0 on success, and >0 if an error occurs.

BUGS
     None known.

BSD                              Sept 27, 2012                             BSD
```