# First execution after compiling is slow in mac

Tags: macos, performance, compile

First execution of a freshly compiled program is very slow, next executions are fast enough, I suspect it is related to the mac trying to verify the binary, but I'd rather avoid this process as I compile files very frequently and I know (at least from files compiled by myself) that they are not harmful.

The most common scenario for me is as follow:

- Write small program in c++ (let's say simple hello world `a.cpp`)
- Compile (`g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp -o sol`)
- Execute it for first time `./sol`  **(takes in the order of 5 seconds)**
- Execute it again `./sol` (gives output instantly as expected)

I already saw few related questions, however I was unable to solve the problem:

- [What should I do about com.apple.quarantine?](https://superuser.com/questions/28384/what-should-i-do-about-com-apple-quarantine)
- [First execution after compiling incredibly slow, unless it's “obvious” that all loops will halt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894776/first-execution-after-compiling-incredibly-slow-unless-its-obvious-that-all)

Comment: You imply that MacOS extended attribute `com.apple.quarantine` is set on your executable `./sol`, well is it? Post us the result of `ls -l@ ./sol`. If it's 100% your own code or you trust it 100%, you can manually remove the extattr with `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine ./sol`. Then recheck with `ls -l@` that it's gone. Does that solve it? Perhaps your compile directory or parent diectory has `com.apple.quarantine` extattr set, if so you need to remove it there, it's sticky and will keep reattaching itself to your executable.

Comment: Also in general for troubleshooting MacOS and g++ behavior, it's useful to tell us what exact versions both of MacOS and g++ you have. Also tell us if you overlaid an install of say MacOS version Y over MacOS X.